# More problems with Jquery src and load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pulling my hair out as to why one of these scripts works, while the other doesn't . Upon clicking the text, the image should change.  And on a side note does the load() command look ok?

What is the difference between these two that's making the first work and the second malfunction?

The functional:

```
CageImg=new Image();
CageImg.src="http://cageme.herokuapp.com/css/mrcage.jpg"

function buttonInCompany() 
{
$('#desc').load('incompany.html'); 
$('#midimg').attr("src",CageImg.src); } 

$(document).ready(function() { $("#someID").click(function() { buttonInCompany(); }); }); </script>

<div id='someID'>Everything is cage's cage.<br><br></div>

<img id="midimg" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BdfyYy_Y0gY/UP_3y3F2RDI/AAAAAAAAC-Q/eHPCltO8bG8/s1600/TomEngelsnicolas+thing.jpg">
```

The non functional:

```
    <script src="jquery.src"></script>
        <script>
        incompanyImage=new Image(); 
        incompanyImage.src= "images/16581370-group-of-happy-young-business-people-in-a-meeting-at-office.jpg" 

function buttonInCompany()

        {
        $('#desc').load('desc.html #incompany');
        $('#midimg').attr("src",incompanyImage.src); } 

        $(document).ready(function() { $("#incompany").click(function() { buttonInCompany(); }); }); 

        </script>

        <div id="incompany" class="art-button">Aulas in-Company</div>

        <img id="midimg" width="233" height="350" src="images/Fotolia_5170186_X-01.jpg"><br></p>
```

Comment: Is the path correct? If you look at the browser's dev tools, does the image file load correctly?

Comment: No, @The Suresh Atta, it didn't work even though i changed the img src identical to that of the functional code. Also load() command isnt working. It seems As though The Button itself isnt working.